C++ not loading variables from header file
I'm trying to learn C++ (slowly) and am trying to get my head around header files. As far as I am aware, I can initialise my variables inside the header file, and then refer to them in my cpp file to use. I am trying to do this, but for some reason the cpp file is loading the header file successfully but not initialising any of the variables.
Have I misunderstood header files?
Header
#pragma once
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES

#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>




class learning_cpp
{
public:
    float SampleRate;

};

C++
#include "learning_cpp.h"

int main() {

    SampleRate = 1000;
};

Error: identifier "SampleRate" is undefined

"I can initialise my variables inside the header file," -- your header file neither initializes anything nor uses any variables. This might be a terminology issue, but it's kind of key to understanding your question.

Hi @JaMiT I added a shorter version like you requested. I thought what the code is doing is in the header file saying that there will be a variable SampleRate that is a float, so that when I run the c++ file I can call that variable without having to initialise it with float SampleRate = 1000;

SampleRate is a public member of class learning_cpp, not a global variable that could be referenced in main. Don't try to learn C++ by trials-and-errors, better follow some good beginners book: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

I would highly recommend using a good c++ book. C++ is very different from other programming languages like python. It cannot be learnt by just trial and error. Before writing any c++ program, refer to a good c++ book so that the basics are cleared first.

Also change <math.h> to <cmath>

@user12002570 May I ask why use cmath over math.h?
I have a textbook I am using by Bjarne Stroustrup I can see on the list you both provided so I will read that a bit more, thanks for the recommendations!

@crankymidlifecrisis Basically cmath is the c++ version and should be used. Similarly use <cstdlib> instead of <stdlib.h>. See cmath vs math.h (And similar c-prefixed vs .h extension headers)

Thanks a lot, I really appreciate the help and info :) much more useful than simply telling me to delete my code ;)

you have member variable not a global variable. Proper answer here requires coping one of first paragraphs from C++ student book. Apparently you have skipped some paragraphs and now you are confused.

Maybe show an example of this working when you don't use a header file? (Since the question squarely puts the blame on using a header file, it can be useful to demonstrate why the blame is warranted.)

All variables in C++ have their own visibility scope. Usually this scope between {}. Let's find that with example below:
int main(void) {
    int my_int_var = 10;
    {
        int my_perfect_double_var = 10.0f;
    }
    /* the scope of my_perfect_double_var is limited to {}, so we can't use that variable here */
    /* but we can use my_int_var, because it have scope of the whole main function */
    my_int_var = 15; /* OK */
    my_perfect_double_var = 12.4f; /* ERROR here */
    
    return 0;
}

According to your code, your variables like SampleRate, Time, Frequency, etc. have scope inside the learning_cpp class. So you can use them ONLY inside an instance of this class
To use them in code, you must first create an instance of the class, and then you can use the variables by accessing them from the instance:
#include "learning_cpp.h"

int main(void) {
    learning_cpp MyClass;
    MyClass.SampleRate = 15;
    MyClass.Frequency = 10;
    ...
}


Thank you this makes sense :) is there a way to define global variables in the header file or is this not possible/not recommended?

Not recommended. Global variables need to be unique, and if you put them in headers they are likely to be multiply defined which will result in link errors. You can have static variables but that can be inefficient.

You can create a global variable in the header file and use it in any .cpp file where you include the header. But the ways to create such a variable, the cases when you should/shouldn't use them, how to use them correctly and any corner cases are so many that this question is "out of scope" for this topic

That makes sense, similar to in other languages, thanks
